# Multi Site Manager site dropdown showing on single site

Tags: multi-site-manager

I have a single site on a fresh install. However, in the top right corner, clicking on the site name gives the dropdown as if this were a multi site install. I am not running MSM.

Additionally, it wasn't clear where to edit the site name, I had to do so in the DB.

Bug?

[image: img]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I feel dumb. For some unknown reason, I had this setting in config.php:

```
$config['multiple_sites_enabled'] = "y";
```

Changed to "n" and now things work as expected.

Palm to forehead.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to edit the site name within the CP under Admin > General Configuration > Site Name.

"Additionally, it wasn't clear where to edit the site name, I had to do so in the DB."

Might you have inadvertently created a new site entry within the exp_sites table when you entered your site name? How many sites do you see when you look at that table?

Answer (score 1):

Try looking inside the system folder if there is this file: system > expressionengine > controllers > cp > sites.php

if it is there, try to delete it